Google Cloud VMware engine vCenter password expiry
GCVE documentation says that vCenter passwords expire after 365 days after which it has to be reset using gcloud vmware private-clouds vcenter credentials reset command. Is there a way to know whether the password has expired or going to expire? Is there a specific exception that gets thrown when I try to fetch the credentials after expiry, so that I can reset it?

That’s right, The accounts created on gve.local single sign-on domain will expire after 365 days along with credentials generated by VMware engine. So if you need to continue using the account then you must update the password.
As mentioned in the documentation:

If the root password expires, you cannot reinstate it. You must implement site-specific policies to prevent administrative and root passwords from expiring.
To verify the password expiry on all accounts log in to your virtual appliance machines as root and run the # more /etc/shadow command.


To modify the expiry of the root account, run the # passwd -x 365 root command.


In this command, 365 specifies the number of days until password expiry. Use the same command to modify any user, substituting the specific account for root and replacing the number of days to meet the expiry standards of the organization.

AFAIK  there isn’t a specific exception thrown when you try to fetch the credentials after expiry.
